# layout_weight doesn't behave as expected

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

In my application I want to position elements under a card view, using `layout_weight` with values .3 and .7. However It seems that, the space it takes is dependant on the text lengh that my card view holds. Here's the example code:

First card view:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_terminal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="14dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/use_card_reader"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#87ceeb"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Read Card"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                card_view:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click here to read the card"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Second Card view:

```
[![<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/manual_entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:src="@drawable/manual_fill"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#87ceeb"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Read Paper"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                card_view:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is some long explanation text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here's the attached image:

[image: enter code here]

As you can see, the second card has an image that is shorter in length, because the text on the right side is longer. How can I fix this that the views will take exactly .3 and .7 of the space, regardless of the text that comes after?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to take static layout height.

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_terminal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="14dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/use_card_reader"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#87ceeb"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Read Card"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                card_view:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click here to read the card"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
                android:textColor="@color/navy"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

layout_weight in LinerLayout to make it work as expected u should take care of this:

if the **LinerLayout** orientation is vertical then the child's height should be **0dp** and the **layout_weight** value will determine the height of the child

if the **LinerLayout** orientation is horizontal then the child's width should be **0dp** and the **layout_weight** value will determine the width of the child

so in your code the child should look like this:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="odp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:src="@drawable/manual_fill"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#87ceeb"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Read Paper"
            android:textColor="@color/navy"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            card_view:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is some long explanation text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
            android:textColor="@color/navy"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```